# Sorting all the columns in MDX queries

Tags: sorting, ssas, mdx, measures

Below is my MDX query. Here I have applied sorting for one column, how can I sort all the columns, the reason behind this is, I no column should have any values like (null), null, empty, unknown etc.

```
WITH MEMBER PageSize AS
  1
MEMBER [PageNumber] AS
  1
MEMBER [Measures].[Orderby Measure] AS
  [Measures].[Budget Delivered COGS]
MEMBER [Orderby] AS
  "BASC"
SET ROWAXISWOF AS
  NonEmpty (
    ( [Time Periods].[Fiscal Year].[Fiscal Year].Members, [Time Periods].[Fiscal Quarter].[Fiscal Quarter].Members, [Time Periods].[Fiscal Month].[Fiscal Month].Members, [Time Periods].[Fiscal Week].[Fiscal Week].Members ),
    {
      { [Measures].[Budget Delivered COGS] },
      { [Measures].[Break Even Delivered] }
    }
  )
SET ROWAXISWF AS
  Filter ( ROWAXISWOF, [Measures].[Budget Delivered COGS] )
SET ROWAXIS AS
  IIf ( 'Filter' = "NotFilter", ROWAXISWF, ROWAXISWOF )
MEMBER [Measures].[MaxRowCount] AS
  ROWAXIS .Count
SET ROWAXIS_Count AS
  IIf (
    'Paging' = "Paging",
    (
    CASE
    WHEN [Orderby] = 'BASC'
    THEN Tail (
      TopCount ( ROWAXIS, PageSize * PageNumber, [Measures].[Orderby Measure] ),
      PageSize
    )
    ELSE Tail (
      BottomCount ( ROWAXIS, PageSize * PageNumber, [Measures].[Orderby Measure] ),
      PageSize
    ) END ),
    ROWAXISWOF
  )
SELECT ( IIf (
  'Paging' = "Paging",
  (
  { [Measures].[Budget Delivered COGS], [Measures].[Break Even Delivered], [Measures].[MaxRowCount] } ),
  { [Measures].[Budget Delivered COGS], [Measures].[Break Even Delivered] }
) ) ON COLUMNS,
ROWAXIS_Count ON ROWS
FROM (
  SELECT (
  { [Time Periods].[Fiscal Year].&[2011], [Time Periods].[Fiscal Year].&[2012], [Time Periods].[Fiscal Year].&[2013], [Time Periods].[Fiscal Year].&[2014], [Time Periods].[Fiscal Year].&[2015] } ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Homestore Sales]
)
```

It will return the output as preceding.

[image]

In that query for the Break Even Delivered header it is showing (null) as the first value . How can we make the value which are not null  to be on top? if that is for one column we can just apply a sorting. My requirement is, no column should have null values in the first cell if any of the cell contains values. Please suggest me any idea. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by myself. I have changed the ROWAXISWOF as follows.

```
SET ROWAXISWOF AS
  NonEmpty (
  NonEmpty (
    ( 
    [Time Periods].[Fiscal Year].[Fiscal Year].Members, [Time Periods].[Fiscal Quarter].[Fiscal Quarter].Members, [Time Periods].[Fiscal Month].[Fiscal Month].Members, [Time Periods].[Fiscal Week].[Fiscal Week].Members 
    ),
      { [Measures].[Budget Delivered COGS] }),
      { [Measures].[Break Even Delivered] }  )
```

I have included NonEmpty conditions for each measures. Hope this will help some one.